# Integration over the hypersurface in Einstein-Hilbert action

Tags: general-relativity, gauss-law, variational-principle, variational-calculus

In the variation of Einstein-Hilbert action the integral of the term $d^4x\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\delta R_{\mu\nu}$ over the spacetime manifold is equal to zero. 
$$I=\underset{\mathcal M}\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\delta R_{\mu\nu}=\underset{\mathcal M}\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}D_{\mu}(g^{\alpha\beta}\delta\Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}-g^{\alpha\mu}\delta\Gamma^{\beta}_{\alpha\beta})$$

Denoting $g^{\alpha\beta}\delta\Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}-g^{\alpha\mu}\delta\Gamma^{\beta}_{\alpha\beta}=\delta\mathcal V^{\mu}:$
$$
\underset{\mathcal M}\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}D_{\mu}\mathcal \delta V^{\mu}=\underset{\partial \mathcal M}\oint d\Sigma_{\mu}\delta\mathcal V^{\mu}=0
$$
where $d\Sigma_{\mu}=n_{\mu}\sqrt{|\gamma|}d^3\xi$, $\gamma$ is $3$-dimensional induced metric. What is the reason of being zero of the integral?

Comment: *Usually* when one is performing the variation of the action to get the equations of motion of the theory and suddenly throws boundary terms away, the non-stated assumption is that the variations of the fields are supposed to be of compact support, meaning that they vanish outside of a compact set. In that case these boundary integrals end up being set to zero. But if the variations are not compactly supported one cannot throw these terms away. In particular they are relevant in defining the sympletic form following Wald's method. Please see e.g. https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.528801.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the divergence of a vector. One can use Stokes theorem and say that this is equal to a boundary contribution at infinty which is what we can set to be equal to zero.

Comment: At the infinity/boundary of a hypersurface, variation is of the metric is zero due to negligible variation of metric?

Comment: We consider that the deformations of the field vanish at the boundary.

Comment: The field is here is the metric field?

Comment: Yes, i refer to the field we vary with respect to.

Comment: This is not correct. The Einstein-Hilbert action contains up to two derivatives in the metric so the boundary term you have written contains $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ and its first derivative. The boundary term vanishes if both $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ AND its derivative vanish on the boundary. Doing this simultaneously turns out to be too strong a condition so we must choose one. The standard boundary condition is to assume that $\delta g_{\mu\nu}|_{\text{bdy}} = 0$. The term involving its derivative then has to be cancelled by ADDING an extra term to the action (see https://tinyurl.com/sh5oh3g).

Comment: @Prahar is right. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ApolloRa - Your edited answer is still incorrect. The boundary term is not zero! That is the whole point of my comment! We need to ADD a second term to the Einstein-Hilbert action (called the GHY term) to cancel this boundary contribution.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9712019.pdf page 115

Comment: @ApolloRa - It is clear that these lecture notes are a very basic introduction to GR and that Carroll is therefore sweeping a lot of things under the rug. This is obviously fine since boundary issues are not something an introductory course is expected to teach. Instead, if you read his textbook (Spacetime and Geometry by Carroll) (the paragraph below eq (4.65)), you will see that he has an extra sentence about the boundary issues that I mentioned. Again, he doesn't discuss it in detail since it derails the main discussion that the author is interested in.